# how to display second column in first column with total

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
Id  ProjectName SubProjectName  Cost
1   Project1    SubProject1 100
2   Project1    SubProject2 60
3   Project2    SubProject3 50
4   Project2    SubProject4 150
5   Project3    SubProject5 200
6   Project4    SubProject6 40
```

i want output like this:

```
project1   160
subproject1 100
subproject1 60
project2    200
subproject3 50
subproject4 150
project3    200
subproject5 200
project4    40
subproject6 40
```

Comment: Hello, could you please explain what you have done so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL`. For example:

```
select projectname, sum(cost) from t group by projectname
union all
select subprojectname, cost from t
```

Now, if you want that exact same order, you can do:

```
select name, cost
from (
  select min(id) as id, 0 as sub, projectname as name, sum(cost) as cost
  from t 
  group by projectname
  union all
  select id, 1, subprojectname, cost from t
) x
order by id, sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the ROLLUP in Group by like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SubProjectName is not null THEN SubProjectName ELSE ProjectName END ProjectName ,SUM(cost) cost FROM TblCost
GROUP BY  ROLLUP (ProjectName,SubProjectName)
ORDER BY ProjectName,SubProjectName
```